# How to filter nested collection in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I've been scouring Stack for the last couple of hours, and while several seem related, nothing appears to be working correctly.

I have a GraphQL API running on Laravel, and am trying to filter out the current_user from a mutator so that I don't have to do it on the frontend.

A User hasMany Trips, and each Trip belongsToMany Users via a pivot table called `trip_user`. On the Trip model, I am eager loading things such as Todos and Users like this:

**Trip.php**

```php
class Trip extends Model
{
    protected $with = [
        'todos', 'shopping_list_items', 'users'
    ];

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    // other relationships
}
```

Then in my TripQuery which returns my results to my GraphQL client, I am trying to return all of a user's trips, but filter out current_user, like so:

```php
class TripsQuery
{
    public function find_by_user($rootValue, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo)
    {
        $user = $context->user();

        if ($user) {
            // all trip friends and todos automatically eager loaded on the model
            $trips = $user->trips()->get();

            return $trips->each->users->filter(function ($friend) use ($user) {
                return $friend->id !== $user->id;
            });
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

When I run this however, the *only* user it's returning is current_user, and for some reason it's returning an empty array of `Todos`, even though it should return 4 of them. I'm not sure why the `->filter()` function isn't working (I am brand new to Laravel, so there's that).

Why isn't the `->filter` working correctly?

**EDIT**
Including the results from a `dd()`:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:9 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Trip 1"
    "description" => "Planning for Trip 1"
    "owner_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2020-11-18T06:28:45.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2020-11-18T06:28:45.000000Z"
    "todos" => array:4 [
      0 => array:6 [
        "id" => 1
        "title" => "Book car rental"
        "checked" => 0
        "trip_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2020-11-18T17:00:46.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2020-11-18T17:00:46.000000Z"
      ]
      1 => array:6 [
        "id" => 2
        "title" => "Check in to flights"
        "checked" => 0
        "trip_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2020-11-18T17:00:46.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2020-11-18T17:00:46.000000Z"
      ]
      2 => array:6 [
        "id" => 3
        "title" => "Drop off dog at sitter"
        "checked" => 1
        "trip_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2020-11-18T17:00:46.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2020-11-18T17:00:46.000000Z"
      ]
      3 => array:6 [
        "id" => 4
        "title" => "Stop at store"
        "checked" => 1
        "trip_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2020-11-18T17:00:46.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2020-11-18T17:00:46.000000Z"
      ]
    ]
    "users" => array:3 [
      0 => array:19 [
        "id" => 1
        "api_token" => null
        "email" => "test@gmail.com"
        "email_verified_at" => "2020-11-07T15:38:48.000000Z"
        "avatar_url" => null
        "created_at" => "2020-11-07T15:38:48.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2020-11-16T20:55:02.000000Z"
        "pivot" => array:2 [
          "trip_id" => 1
          "user_id" => 1
        ]
      ]
      1 => array:19 [
        "id" => 2
        "api_token" => null
        "email" => "michael.scott@gmail.com"
        "email_verified_at" => "2020-11-07T15:38:48.000000Z"
        "avatar_url" => null
        "created_at" => "2020-11-07T15:38:48.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2020-11-07T15:38:48.000000Z"
        "pivot" => array:2 [
          "trip_id" => 1
          "user_id" => 2
        ]
      ]
      2 => array:19 [
        "id" => 3
        "api_token" => null
        "email" => "pam.beasley@gmail.com"
        "email_verified_at" => "2020-11-07T15:38:48.000000Z"
        "avatar_url" => null
        "created_at" => "2020-11-07T15:38:48.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2020-11-07T15:38:48.000000Z"
        "pivot" => array:2 [
          "trip_id" => 1
          "user_id" => 3
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:9 [
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Trip 2"
    "description" => "Trip 2 Description"
    "owner_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2020-11-18T06:28:45.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2020-11-18T06:28:45.000000Z"
    "todos" => []
    "shopping_list_items" => []
    "users" => array:1 [
      0 => array:19 [
        "id" => 1
        "api_token" => null
        "email" => "benny.timkins@gmail.com"
        "email_verified_at" => "2020-11-07T15:38:48.000000Z"
        "avatar_url" => null
        "created_at" => "2020-11-07T15:38:48.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2020-11-16T20:55:02.000000Z"
        "pivot" => array:2 [
          "trip_id" => 2
          "user_id" => 1
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: What does `dd($trips->toArray());` show you?

Comment: It gives me an array with the two test trips that are in my database

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output. Text, not screenshot.

Comment: I've updated the post with the results

Comment: Do you want to return trips without current user in the relation?

Comment: Yep exactly. So a Trip would have several users attached to it as a relation, and I'd like the current_user to be removed from that relation while keeping other eager_loaded relations intact.

Comment: It would make more sense to do this filtering at the relationship level using a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes) or [when you retrieve it](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

Comment: This looks promising. If I add the eager_load constraint, can I define that on the model inside of the `protected $with` property, or will I need to eager_load in the mutator function?

Comment: If you want to do it at the model level, I'd suggest a second relationship method that applies the filter. e.g. `return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->where(...);`

Answer (score 1):

Each does only return current collection for chaining oportunity, [does not mutate the collection](https://github.com/illuminate/collections/blob/7ab412ee20ef2a4d4574f731a16dfcb8fe64b5c9/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php#L231).

I think the correct solution from how it looks like you use `GraphQL`, is to filter the eager loading using the `with()` method and adding a query to it.

```
return $user->trips()->with(['users' => function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->where('id', '!=', $user->id);
}])->get();
```

For better code style, never check for a condition, invert it and return early.

```
$user = $context->user();

if (! $user) {
    return null;
}

return $user->trips()->with(['users' => function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->where('users.id', '!=', $user->id);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Ah I was just messing around with using the `->where` function! When trying this out, I received a rather large error related to SQLSTATE: `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `users`.*, `trip_user`.`trip_id` as `pivot_trip_id`, `trip_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id` from `users` inner join `trip_user` on `users`.`id` = `trip_user`.`user_id` where `trip_user`.`trip_id` in (1, 2) and `id` != 1)",`

Comment: That removes the error, however it unfortunately still retains the current_user

Comment: How do you retrieve the user relation? if you refetch em, the constraint will be removed

Comment: I should probably mention that I have a pivot table with `user_id` and `trip_id` columns. When I eager_load `users` from a Trip, it pulls all associated users in through the pivot.

Comment: But im pretty certain this should work, how do you transform your trips for the api?

Comment: I'm just using the Lighthouse package which builds the GraphQL client on top of Laravel. When I run it in the GraphQL Playground, it goes through the TripQuery `find_by_user` function that I've defined above. I hope that's what you're asking, I apologize if I'm not quite getting it.